# Unexpected inheritance between python classes

Tags: python, class, dictionary, inheritance, attributes

I have two python classes `A` and `B`. Class `B` takes class `A` as an input variable. The reason I do this instead of making `A` a parent class of `B` is that `A` is very cpu-consuming in my case (the code below is just a simplified example). Therefore I always save class `A` as a pickle file so that I can reuse it. In class `A`, a list of dictionaries `my_list` is saved as an attribute. Then in class `B` it copies `A().my_list` to `B().my_new_list` and adds two new key-value pairs. The simplified code is shown below:

```
import random

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.make_list()
    def make_list(self):
        self.my_list = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}]

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, classA):
        self.my_new_list = classA.my_list.copy()
        self.make_new_list()
    def make_new_list(self):
        for d in self.my_new_list:
            d['d'] = random.randrange(10)
            d['e'] = random.randrange(10)
```

The weird thing happens when I call class `B` multiple times with the same input class `A`. For example, if I call it 5 times:

```
clsA = A() 
for _ in range(5):
    print(clsA.my_list) # I expect clsA.my_list to always be [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}]
    print(B(classA=clsA).my_new_list)
```

I get the following output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 7}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 6, 'e': 3}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 7}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 6, 'e': 3}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 0, 'e': 5}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 2, 'e': 6}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 0, 'e': 5}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 2, 'e': 6}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 5, 'e': 5}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 5, 'e': 8}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 5, 'e': 5}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 5, 'e': 8}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 5, 'e': 7}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 5, 'e': 7}]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 9, 'e': 2}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 6, 'e': 3}]
```

Obviously, something very unexpected happened: class `B` somehow someway changes the input class `A` after the first call. **I expect the `A` class to be invariant so that I can reuse the same class `A` multiple times**, which will save me a lot of cpu time. Anyone knows the reason for this unexpected inheritance, and how to change my code? Note that **I don't want to make `B` a child class of `A`**.

Comment: This isn't inheritance, it's aliasing. The problem is that you are making a shallow copy of the list, which doesn't copy the dictionaries.

Comment: thanks. deepcopy seems to work now